# Multiple view with same resource id in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view

I have only one listview in a fragment with other views.

As shown in the view dump below, for some reason, there are two listviews in the hierarchy (with same resource id).

The unpopulated listview (top one) here I think, masks my populated listview.

What is this listview (that is selected in the screenshot) and how can I remove it/find its origin.

[image: a view hierarchy dump of my application]

My code for this fragment looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/dark"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/empty_view"/>

    <include layout="@layout/progress_bar"/>

    <com.application.custom.CustomListView
        android:id="@+id/main_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE:

The activity simply loads the fragments:

```
    HomeFrag homeFragment = new HomeFrag();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.homelist_fragment_container, homeFragment, "home_fragment")
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are using `add` to add the fragment, without checking if the fragment exists. This resulted in multiple view hierarchies with same resource ids.

Adding the following check to see if the fragment already exists, around the add fragment code fixes this:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_frag_tag") == null) {
    //add fragment with tag "my_frag_tag"
    HomeFrag homeFragment = new HomeFrag();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.homelist_fragment_container, homeFragment, "my_frag_tag")
        .commit();
}
```

This also ensures that the fragment isn't created when there is no need to create it (unlike `replace`).